# Display Polls with a custom template shows only empty results

Tags: magento-1.9, wysiwyg, widget, custom-block, variables

## Meta

- Magento 1.9.2.1
- Custom Template
- Poll works fine when in sidebar
- Poll works fine when loaded by layout xml

## History

Based on this information:

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-frontend/reusing-magento-poll-on-any-page-or-any-block/

and

https://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/how-to-display-the-magento-poll-voting-form-and-results-in-a-static-block/

I'd like to show the polls module anywhere I like, using the WYSIWYG Editor.

When I add the poll on a CMS page, by adding the xml to the design tab of the new page, it all works fine. This is not available in a static CMS Block. Since I need the poll to appear in a static block, I run into a little problem.

## The problem

Loading the Poll with

`{{block type="poll/poll" template="poll/active.phtml" poll_id="1"}} 
{{block type="poll/poll" template="poll/result.phtml" poll_id="1"}}`

does indeed show the poll and the results. Of course, the appear both at the same time and the results are empty.

## Attempt for a solution

I tried to emulate the way the template is changed, when it's done with xml.
So I created `poll/anywhere.phtml` like this:

```
<?php
    $pollId = $this->getPollId();
    $poll = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('poll/activePoll');
    $poll->setPollId($pollId);
    $poll->setPollTemplate('poll/result.phtml', 'results');
    $poll->setPollTemplate('poll/active.phtml', 'poll');
    echo $poll->toHtml();
?>
```

Then I load This template in the WYSIWYG Editor via:

`{{block type="page/html" template="poll/anywhere.phtml" poll_id="2"}}`

This leads to the same behaviour, as when I load both parts separately, only that the poll itself does not show (correct in this case), but the results are still empty.

Again, when I load it with xml, it works as expected.

For reference (from the first link), this look like this:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="poll/activePoll" name="custom.poll">
        <action method="setPollId">
            <pollId>1</pollId>
        </action>
        <action method="setPollTemplate">
            <template>poll/active.phtml</template>              
            <type>poll</type>
        </action>
        <action method="setPollTemplate">
            <template>poll/result.phtml</template>      
            <type>results</type>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

From What I see, the same thing should be accomplished in `anywhere.phtml`

## The question

Is obviously, what did I do wrong, what did I miss?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Allow block in whitelist in `admin-> system-> permission-> blocks-> add new block`

Enter "poll/poll" in **Block name** and "Yes" in **Is Allowed** 
     it should resolve your issue when you use `poll/anywhere.phtml` - template